# Exposing any Ruby object over the Web

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain how the following Ruby code works? (taken from [gist: 675667](https://gist.github.com/675667))

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'

class Object
  def webapp
    class << self
       define_method :call do |env|
         func, *attrs = env['PATH_INFO'].split('/').reject(&:empty?)
         [200, {}, [send(func, *attrs).to_s]]
       end
    end
    self
  end
end

Rack::Handler::Mongrel.run [].webapp, :Port => 9292
#                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
#                              |          (x)
#                         ROFLSCALE DB ---/
#
```

If we run it, we can access it over the Web:

```
GET http://localhost:9292/push/1  -> 1
GET http://localhost:9292/push/2  -> 12
GET http://localhost:9292/push/3  -> 123
GET http://localhost:9292/to_a    -> 123
GET http://localhost:9292/pop     -> 3
GET http://localhost:9292/shift   -> 1
```

Of course, we can run something like:

```
GET http://localhost:9292/instance_eval/exec("rm -rf /")
```

Anyways... how does it work? Can you walk me through the code step-by-step?

Answer (score 10):

The class `Object` is the base class for all objects in Ruby. A new method `webapp` is defined on this, which makes it callable for all objects.

When calling `webapp`, the method `self.define_method` is called on the objects class (But only for that particular object - That's called a [meta-class](http://web.archive.org/web/20080527003126/http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html), by the way). This defines a new method `call` for its instance (Eg. the object).

This new `call` method takes `env` as argument and splits `PATH_INFO` by forward-slashes and stores in an array. The first element is then assigned to a variable `func`, and the remainder to a variable `attrs` . Then the magic method `send` is invoked, which basically calls a method by the name of the variable `func`. It then returns an array, consisting of a status-code (200), an empty hash and the output of the method-call.

On the final line, a new array instance is created (`[]` is shorthand for `Array.new`). Then the method `webapp` is called on it, which enriches it with the `call` method, as explained above. `webapp` conveniently returns `self`. So you can pass it directly to `Rack::Handler::Mongrel.run`, which will launch a web server (Mongrel is the web server - Rack is an abstraction-layer that gives different web servers a uniform interface). The server will pass requests to the `call` method, and interpret the return value to send a response back.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how familiar you are with ruby - let me know what doesn't make sense.

Lines 1 and 2 import the libraries needed to start a webserver.

Then on line 4, the base class `Object` is reopened to add a new method to it - you can do this anywhere you like in ruby. All classes inherit from `Object`, so whatever methods you define here can be called on any object.

Line 5 begins defining a new method for all objects, called `webapp`.

Line 6 and 7 define a method `call` for each instance of `Object` that is instantiated. I think this is basically equivalent to using `self.call` to define the method.

Lines 8 takes the relative part of the URL (eg `push/1` or `to_a`) and splits it into two parts, (ie `func` and a variable length string of `attrs`).

Line 9 then returns a raw HTTP response, comprised of the status code (`200`), headers (empty in this case: `{}`), and body `([send(func, *attrs).to_s])`

The body is comprised of the response of the object to the method `func`, with the arguments `attrs`. So if the URL requested was `push/1`, the method `push` would be called with the argument `1`. This is equivalent to `[push(1).to_s]`. The `to_s` converts the value that is returned by the method to a string.

Finally, on line 16, a webserver is started on port 9292. The object that the `webapp` method is called on is an empty array - you could use a `String` (ie `''`), or a `Hash` (ie `{}`) or a `Proc` (ie `Proc.new`) or any ruby class you like.

You can then manipulate the object by hitting URLs of the form `func/attribute1/attribute2/attribute3...`, and the object will call the method `func` with the string of arguments `attribute1, attribute2, attribute3...`.

Interesting code!